# Can I identify songs somewhere?

Tags: discussion

I know the sounds of 2 songs that I'd like to identify. Is music.stackexchange the best place to ask (The two songs are 1 70s disco that goes Keep on dancing (I know many songs are like that but I will recognize it when I hear it again, I think it was 1978 or 79.) Then the other is funk where a vocal sampled says One one one two..one one one two...

I'm 100 % certain that the songs are real but I could not find them. The closest I could was matching them at other material that came 1978-1979.

Updated: Found this [How to identify a particular song or piece?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17094/how-to-identify-a-particular-song-or-piece)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Song identification is off-topic on Music.SE. Some of the people in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room) might be able to help (asking about this there is fine), but the real Stack Exchange place for this might be a site that is currently in proposal form only: See [Music Fans on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans?referrer=TUOcpcSyRDhlGleSE5XxcQ2). That proposal needs about 70 more committers (at this time) before the site enters beta.

Comment: Thanks. I found good similar Q and A http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17094/how-to-identify-a-particular-song-or-piece

Comment: @NiklasRtz Yes, that one exists, but basically only because it is general; the idea of that one is to provide ways how to do it, not to provide an identify-this service. Even that question may be considered off-topic by someone, but IMHO it's fine.

Comment: It's now public at: http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/, so could you rephrase your answer?

Comment: @kenorb Feel free to submit an edit!

Comment: I've tried, but I couldn't, since I've too less repo here.